# Can the two sides of a SQL Set operation be correlated?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, sql-except

Is there someway in SQL to correlate the sides of a set operation?

I want to run a query like

```
SELECT * except(id) FROM mytable where id = 1
EXCEPT DISTINCT
SELECT * except(id) FROM mytable where id = 2
```

Only I have thousands of pairs of `(1,2)` which I want to compare ie. `(2,3)`, `(3,4)`

I could write something like:

```
with numbers as (
  SELECT n FROM unnest(generate_array(1,100)) n
)

,sample_data as (
  SELECT 
    n as id,
    n2, 
    date_add(current_date(), interval n2 day ) d 
  FROM numbers 
  CROSS JOIN unnest(generate_array(numbers.n, 100)) n2
)

SELECT sample_data.* except(id) 
FROM sample_data 
INNER JOIN numbers on n = id
EXCEPT DISTINCT
SELECT sample_data.* except(id) 
FROM sample_data 
INNER JOIN numbers ON sample_data.id = numbers.n + 1
```

But this gives only differences for the lowest id as all of the others are in both sets of the except operator.

---

"Expected result"

I've been asked for sample data and an expected result in the comments.  I think that these obscure my question rather than explain it, but here goes.

If the first query is run 100 times, each time it returns one row, as id 1 and id 2 each have 100 rows 99 of which match. I want a result with 100 rows returned for this sample data, with n2 being 1 through 100.

To be really clear, there are a hundred ways to generate the numbers 1 through 100. The question itself includes the best one.  Doing so is not part of my question.  The question is about correlating the queries on either side of the `EXCEPT` keyword.

---

I have plenty of work arounds already.  The obvious one is to issue the `EXCEPT` query many times from a program written outside SQL.  The much better performing one is to generate a statement with all of the columns and a `lead` or `lag` of each column and filter in a `qualify` clause if any of the the columns have changed.  That column-by-column-lag query is long and hard to read, but my question largely my academic curiosity.

Comment: Please add sample data.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I've added data.  I hope it helps

Comment: still not clear - can you provide expected output?